# Size Scale Disappears ggplotly

Tags: r, plotly

When I try to use ggplotly(), I lose the legend that explains the color scale. If I use color instead of size the legend appears. How do I get the legend to appear when using size?

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

plot <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, size = disp, frame = hp)) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(plot) %>%
  layout(showlegend = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that using as size a numeric variable such as disp will create a very large legend e.g.:

```
p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, colour=factor(disp), size = factor(disp))) +
geom_point() 
p <- ggplotly(p)
p
```

PS: I'm not sure you can use `frame` and still have the desired legend using `ggplotly`.

**Option 2:** Use directly `plot_ly` e.g.:

```
plot_ly(mtcars,x = ~ mpg, y= ~ cyl,  size = ~disp , type='scatter', mode = 'markers', frame = ~disp) %>%
layout(showlegend = T)
```

Comment: I don't think that the plot_ly version has a legend that includes size. There is a legend with a sample point, but nothing to show the reader what that sample point represents. I would like a legend like the one for the "plot" ggplot object that I made in my question.

Comment: Since the figure is dynamic, I wouldn't expect to have a static legend when you have a large number of data points. However, the figure displays dynamically the disp value in the right-hand side of the slide.